# unable to install openmesh

Tags: python, package, spyder

I am having difficulties installing openmesh. (https://pypi.org/project/openmesh/)
(https://justpaste.it/2lwdi) Attached is the log of command prompt when I tried to execute command

```
pip install openmesh
```

I tried conda but same error. I installed Cmake. No change. (I am using Spyder 4.1 on a Windows 10 Machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried lots of things. Nothing worked.
Then I uninstalled current Anaconda distribution and installed this 3 year older one.
Anaconda3-5.3.1-Windows-x86_64.exe
from [https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/](https://archive)

This worked.